# WPF Use text color from resource

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a file with colors called Colors.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ErgoRythm">
    <Color x:Key="TextColor1">#696969</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In my App.xaml I have

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="CustomStyles" Source="Colors.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And now I want to add the color to a text but I get an 'The resource "TextColor1" has an incompatible type.' when I use

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Genearal Volume" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="20" Foreground="{DynamicResource TextColor1}" />
```

Comment: Foreground is a Brush, not a Color.

Comment: So write either `<Brush x:Key="TextBrush1">#696969</Brush>` or `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBrush1" Color="{StaticResource TextColor1}"/>`

Comment: As background information, the reason both `Color` and `SolidColorBrush` exist is because properties that can take brushes can take different types of brushes. So it's possible to fill `Foreground` and `Background` (and others) with something more than a simple color. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-brushes-overview

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments `Foreground` is a `SolidColorBrush` not a color.  So change:

```xml
<Color x:Key="TextColor1">#696969</Color>
```

to this:

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextColor1" Color="#696969"/>
```

Comment: Adding to this, you may consider keeping the `Color` resource and adding a `SolidColorBrush` resource that uses that `Color`. When designing application themes, it's sometimes worthwhile having a handful (3-5) of colors act as an application-wide palette and then creating a number of purpose-built application brushes that utilize just those 3-5 colors.